# Can only create List of a GraphQLType but got: undefined

Tags: schema, graphql, graphql-js

I have a schema that looks like:

UserType :

```
import NotebookType from './NotebookType';
export default new GraphQLObjectType ({
    name: 'User',
    notebook: new GraphQLList(NotebookType)
});
```

NotebookType:

```
import UserType from './UserType';
export default new GraphQLObjectType ({
    name: 'Notebook',
    authors: new GraphQLList(UserType)
});
```

The idea is that each user can have authored multiple notebooks and each notebook can have been edited by multiple authors, all of whom need to be stored so that they can be fetched.

Now, the problem is that I think this is causing a circular dependency issue as I am having an error:

> Error: Can only create List of a GraphQLType but got: undefined.

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and the solution [here](https://gist.github.com/fbaiodias/77406c29ddf37fe46c3c) worked for me.

Try making `authors` and `notebook` functions.

`notebook: () => new GraphQLList(NotebookType)`

`authors: () => new GraphQLList(UserType)`